# "Failed to complete Gradle execution." "Cause: Server redirected too many times (20)"

Tags: android, android-studio

I was having some issue with Eclipse, so decided to try out Android Studio.  I imported the current project that I had started in Eclipse.  Every time I go to build this project, I get the error,

"Failed to complete Gradle execution."  "Cause: Server redirected too many times (20)"

Any idea how to get past this.  It's quite annoying.

Comment: I found a solution.  I fixed Eclipse and went back to it.